# How to use update a column when another column is updated?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table de which has 3 columns id(primary key int),A(int) and B(int).

My requirement is to update B when ever there is an update on A.

So I used trigger and I tried as follows

```
 create trigger deTrigger on [dbo].[de]
 for update
 As
 declare @aValue int;
 select @aValue=i.A from inserted i;
 update de set B =@aValue 
 GO
```

but I dont know how to use `where` condition in the above update query so when ever I update A in a single record then all the rows of B col are updated.

If there is alternate way of using trigger then also please suggest

Comment: You need to use key columns from inserted so that only the wanted rows are updated. Also inserted can contain more than one row, with fetching data into variables you can't handle it correctly.

Comment: @JamesZ so what's the solution?

Comment: Probably something like "update d set B=i.A from inserted i join de d on i.xxx = d.xxx and i.yyy = d.yyy" where the xxx and yyy columns are the keys which identifies the correct rows

Comment: @JamesZ probably you mean primary key

Comment: Why do you want two columns with the same value?

Comment: @MartinSmith OFF THE TOPIC,are you closely following my question? how you are alerted that dudi has posted an answer? do you have any specific provision as you have high reps?

Comment: No, not particularly, editing an answer or adding a new one moves it up to the top of the active list for sql-server.

Comment: @ SpringLearner-you can add to chrome StackStalker extention so you can follow any question you want for any new answer or comments .

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER deTrigger 
ON [dbo].[de]
FOR UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE de 
    SET B = i.A
    FROM Inserted i
    INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.ID = d.ID
    WHERE i.ID = de.ID
      AND i.A <> d.A
 GO
```

Basically, you need to **join** to the `Inserted` pseudo table (since it could contain **multiple rows**), and you also need to join to the `Deleted` pseudo table. Comparing the values from `Inserted` and `Deleted`, you can get those rows that had an update to column `A`, and with those, you can set the value of `B` in your `de` table

Comment: Thanks for answering,Can you please explaing more why should I use deleted and if I dont use then what will be the problem. Also will it cause probelm if I follow as per @JamesZ suggested in comments

Comment: @SpringLearner: by comparing `Inserted` (the *new* values after the `UPDATE`) and `Deleted` (the old values before `UPDATE`), you can find out which rows had a change in column `A` .... If you don't do this, then you might be updating column `B` in a case when something else in the table has been changed - not column A specifically

Comment: let me give a try as per your answer

Answer (score 1):

The standard SQL Server trigger is an "after" trigger. This is useful for updating logs and other types of "after the fact" uses. But you want to modify the incoming stream before it even gets to the table.

For this you need a "before" trigger.

Which SQL Server doesn't have...

Not to worry though, SQL Server *does* have an "instead of" trigger. Originally intended only for views, it has conveniently been made available for tables as well, probably so MS developers don't have to go to all the trouble of implementing "before" triggers.

Here is an example. A schedule table has a datetime field (SchedDate) and an associated integer field (SchedHour) which contains only the hour of the datetime field. So whenever SchedDate is changed, the hour must be written to SchedHour.

```
create trigger T_Schedule_bu ON Schedule 
instead of update as begin
    set NoCount On;

    update  s
        set s.Field1    = i.Field1,
            s.Field2    = i.Field2,
            s.SchedDate = i.SchedDate,
            s.SchedHour = 
                case when i.SchedDate <> s.SchedDate
                     then DatePart( hour, i.SchedDate )
                     else s.SchedHour
                end
    from    Schedule    s
    join    inserted    i
        on  i.ID    = s.ID
end;
```

The other fields are changed unconditionally; SchedHour is changed only if SchedDate has also been changed. Actually, in this particular example, it's not really necessary to perform that test. It just shows how that would be done.

If you're not familiar with "instead of" triggers, just know that the trigger itself must ultimately execute the DML to the target table or it doesn't happen. So one way to render a table "read only" is create an "instead of" trigger that does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

try this code-

```
create trigger deTrigger
on [dbo].[de]
for update
As
    update de
    set B = i.A
    FROM INSERTED i
    WHERE de.id in (SELECT i.ID
        FROM inserted i)
```